# How to get coordinates in double click - MapBox React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, coordinates, mapbox

I plan on implementing a feature of displaying nearby routes when a user double clicks a location, but I dont know how to get the coordinates

This is my current code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Map from 'react-map-gl';
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache, ApolloProvider, gql, useQuery } from '@apollo/client';

const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: TOKEN,
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});

function handleClick(map, event) {
  var lngLat = event.lngLat;
  console.log(lngLat)
}

function App() {

  return (
    <><ApolloProvider client={client}>
    </ApolloProvider>
    
    <Map
    mapboxAccessToken=TOKEN
    initialViewState={{
      longitude: 121.04042520880047,
      latitude: 14.649743779882588,
      zoom: 14
      }}
    style={{ width: window.innerWidth, height: window.innerHeight }}
    mapStyle="mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v11"
    onDblClick={handleClick}
    ></Map>
    </>
  );
}

export default App
```

It leads to this Error:

> ERROR
> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'lngLat')
> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'lngLat')
> at handleClick (http://localhost:3000/main.3e317df54a291f15fa87.hot-update.js:35:22)
> at Mapbox._onPointerEvent (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:34680:9)
> at Map.fire (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors-node_modules_mapbox-gl_dist_mapbox-gl_js.chunk.js:1007:32)
> at Mapbox._fireEvent (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:35107:14)
> at hr._firePreventable (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors-node_modules_mapbox-gl_dist_mapbox-gl_js.chunk.js:26089:23)
> at hr.dblclick (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors-node_modules_mapbox-gl_dist_mapbox-gl_js.chunk.js:26068:21)
> at Xr.handleEvent (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors-node_modules_mapbox-gl_dist_mapbox-gl_js.chunk.js:27078:93)

Comment: have you tried to console log event just to see what's in it ?

Comment: Hi, the error is also displayed in the console